# jQuery function load reloads the whole page

Tags: jquery, function, load, reloading

I'm trying to refresh part of my php page without reloading the whole page using function load(). 
This question has been asked before and i've tried all the solutions I found.

It works well the first time I click on my `<a class="remove" href="...>` but it reloads the entire page on the second click and so on...

It is my first post here but I hope my explanations were clear. Here's the js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".remove").on('click', function(event){
    var url = $(this).attr('href') ;
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#containerWrapper').load(url + " #containerWrapper");
});
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to delegate click event to containerWrapper level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will reload the entire page, because the `.remove` element is a child of `#containerWrapper`. You need to delegate the event to this level, otherwise all bound events will be lost:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#containerWrapper').on('click', ".remove", function (event) {
        var url = this.href;
        event.preventDefault();    
        $('#containerWrapper').load(url + " #containerWrapper");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that it works, any specific reason why it reloaded on the second click? Because the loss of the bound?

Answer (score -1):

first of all this is ,y advice to use

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
//your codes here
});
```

instead of `$(document).ready()` 
I've used some codes exactly like yours and it works great. but just one difference!

```
$(".remove").on('click', function(event){
    var url = $(this).attr('href') ;
   $('#containerWrapper').load(url + " #inner");
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

I've put `prevent` in the end! and I've load the `#inner` inside the `#containerWrapper`
url page markup :

```
<div id="containerWrapper">
   <div id="inner">
   </div>
</div>
```